# Change Swift Version Project is Built With

Tags: swift, xcode, vapor

I'm using Vapor, and I've run into a problem where the change to Xcode 13.3 from 13.1 now means the project (without changes) will no longer build.

How can I change the version of Swift that a Vapor project will build to? Since this isn't an app, the usual convenient configuration UI isn't available, so I presume this has to be done in a configuration file, or via the terminal. Just don't know how, is all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you mean is the version of `swift-tools` that gets invoked rather than `swift`. Change the first line of `Package.swift` in your project's folder to use the current version needed by the latest vapor version 4:

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.5
```

Then use Xcode to try to build. If this doesn't work, try Using the `Clean Build Folder` menu option off the `Product` menu and try again.

Failing this, use terminal to remove the .build folder in your project's folder and do a `swift package update` followed by a `swift build`. I know of at least one swift compiler bug that means a compile that fails with `swift build` will succeed with `swift build -c release` so it could be worth trying both.

If all this fails, include more detail in your question to show the exact cause of 'will no longer build'.